# Google Cloud Storage vs Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get a REST client working with my Google storage buckets. What exactly is the difference between the "Google Cloud Storage" and the "Google Cloud Storage JSON API" API?

Comment: "Google Cloud Storage" and "Google Cloud Storage JSON API" are not different products. In fact the product is "Google Cloud Storage" and as Mike mentions, it offers you two APIs flavors and some client libraries. I suggest to take a look at this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Storage has both an [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) a [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api), so if someone refers to the "Google Cloud Storage API" they could be referring to either one.